# SQL Joint 2 table without duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, join, duplicates, rows

I`m trying to combine 2 tables without duplicate rows

Table 1 - modx_site_content

```
|id|pagetitle|introtext|pub_date|
---------------------------------
|3635| name1 |texttextt|17.02.2015
|3636| name1 |texttextt|18.02.2015
```

Table 2 - modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues

```
|contentid|tmplvarid|value|
---------------------------
|   3635  |    1    |value1
|   3635  |    1    |value2
|   3636  |    1    |value3
```

I`m try to make all

```
|id|title|introtext|publishdate|photo|
--------------------------------------
|3635|name1|texttextt|17.02.2015|value1, value2
|3636|name1|texttextt|18.02.2015|value3
```

But the current result shows dublicate rows id 3535

```
|id|title|introtext|publishdate|photo|
--------------------------------------
|3635|name1|texttextt|17.02.2015|value1
|3635|name1|texttextt|17.02.2015|value2
|3636|name1|texttextt|18.02.2015|value3
```

My current sql resuest is

```
SELECT 
    modx_site_content.id,
    pagetitle as 'title',
    introtext,
    pub_date as 'publishdate',
    modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value as 'photo' 

FROM `modx_site_content`, 
    `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`

WHERE parent IN (1153,3271) 
    AND pub_date>0
    AND `contentid`= modx_site_content.id
    AND `tmplvarid` IN (10, 15, 19) 

Order by `pub_date` DESC LIMIT 20
```

Comment: you'd need a `group by` combined with `group_concat()` on your `select`, and note that what you're doing is poor database practice. do not denormalize your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to your immediate problem is `group by` and `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT c.id, c.pagetitle as title, c.introtext, c.pub_date as publishdate,
       group_concat(cv.value) as sphotos
FROM `modx_site_content` c JOIN
     `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` cv
     ON cv.`contentid`= c.id
WHERE c.parent IN (1153, 3271) AND c.pub_date > 0 AND
      `tmplvarid` IN (10, 15, 19) 
GROUP BY c.id, c.pagetitle, c.introtext, c.pub_date
Order by c.`pub_date` DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

I would also recommend:

- Use explicit `join` syntax.
- Define table aliases in the `from` clause.
- Use table aliases for column references.
- Don't use single quotes to define column aliases.  You don't need an escape character for yours, so don't both using one.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has group_concat that may work (depending on data type):

```
SELECT 
    modx_site_content.id,
    pagetitle as 'title',
    introtext,
    pub_date as 'publishdate',
    group_concat(modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues.value) as 'photo' 
FROM `modx_site_content` JOIN
    `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues` ON `contentid`= modx_site_content.id
WHERE parent IN (1153,3271) 
    AND pub_date>0
    AND `tmplvarid` IN (10, 15, 19) 
GROUP BY modx_site_content.id, pagetitle , introtext, pub_date
```